# missing metrics from apache beam in Prometheus

Tags: java, metrics, apache-beam

quick question. I am trying to present beam metrics in Prometheus. 
I did that in my code: `Counter counter = Metrics.counter(MinimalWordCount.class, "myDummyCounter");` but unfortunately it is still not present in Prometheus.

Question is related to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013889/apache-beam-counter-metrics-not-available-in-flink-webui/50695668?noredirect=1#comment88400685_50695668)

Comment: What is your runner? How are you exporting your metrics?

Comment: I am using flinkRunner. for now, it is irrelevant what I am exporting. I just want to see mentioned Beam counter metric in Prometheus.